# Hierarchical order failure in a Matlab Graph, containing more than 100 nodes

Tags: matlab, graph

With more than 100 nodes in a graph I lose the hierarchical order of matlab graph in my figure, and don't know what exactly is missing or wrong.

Here is an example of a graph including 100 nodes, and everything is as needed.

```
NodeNum = 100;

s = [];
t= [];
for i = 2:NodeNum
    t=[t,i];
end

for j=2:NodeNum/2
    s=[s,j];
    s=[s,j];
end
s=[1,s];

p=graph(s,t);
plot(p)
```

[image: True hierarchical order]

But as soon as number of nodes exceeds a hundred;

```
NodeNum = 102;
s = [];
t= [];
for i = 2:NodeNum
    t=[t,i];
end
for j=2:NodeNum/2
    s=[s,j];
    s=[s,j];
end
s=[1,s];
p=graph(s,t);
plot(p)
```

it looks like here;

[image: False configuration]

Can I resolve this problem for whatever number of nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the cause of the issue is that if you do not specify a graph plotting layout option explicitly to the command `plot`, MATLAB chooses a default plot layout (see the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html)). I believe that the default layout option that was chosen for your graph was `'subspace'`. However, it has a different behaviour depending on whether the number of nodes in the graph is above or below 100 (this is briefly mentioned in the documentation, but I did not find a detailed explanation).

I think the best way to resolve the issue is to use the `'layered'` layout, e.g. `plot(p,'Layout','layered')`.

If you would also like to add node labels (as in your original plot), you can add the option `NodeLabel`, e.g. `plot(p,'Layout','layered', 'NodeLabel', 1:102);`